# toString method printing array instead of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, tostring

I am new to programming and taking an intro to programming javascript class and my assignment keeps printing an array instead of a string when using the toString method. I have been unable to find relevant information to help solve this problem. The assignment is to:

Create a constructor function called World (constructors should be named with a capital letter).

The World object should have a property called plan which is an array of strings.

Create a prototype method for World that prints out the value of the array, with line breaks between each element (the line break character is \n)

Create an instance of the variable world and call its toString method.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function World(plan){
  this.plan = plan;  
}

var plan = ["––––––––––",
            "|   _    |",
            "|  |     |",
            "|__|     |",
            "| ___|   |",
            "––––––––––"];

var funWorld = new World(plan);

World.prototype.plan = function() {
    console.log(this.plan + "\n");
    return this;
};

World.prototype.toString = function() {
    return(this.plan);
};
console.log(funWorld.toString());
```

This is what is printing:

```
[
0:  "––––––––––"
1:  "|   _    |"
2:  "|  |     |"
3:  "|__|     |"
4:  "| ___|   |"
5:  "––––––––––"
]
```

I guess what I'm asking is where did I go wrong?

Comment: your toString() function just returns `this.plan`. where are you converting it to string?

Comment: I don't know enough about this to even know if I'm doing this correctly so I think I am missing the part where I convert it to string. My instructor hasn't offered much help yet on what I am doing wrong which is why I've turned here for help.

Comment: javascript has 2 methods that might help you. try join() and toString() method.

Answer (score 3):

You are shadowing the prototype *method* `plan`, with an *instance property* of the same name.

Your `toString` method simply returns the instance property, which is an array.

Not really seeing the point of a separate *plan* method - you can just contain the logic inside `toString`.

```js
function World(plan){
  this.plan = plan;  
}

World.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.plan.join('\n');
};

var world = new World(["––––––––––",
                      "|   _    |",
                      "|  |     |",
                      "|__|     |",
                      "| ___|   |",
                      "––––––––––"]);
                     
console.log(world.toString());
```